# Undo Deny ALL Permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

On a Windows 2003 server someone set the permissions on a folder to deny EVERYTHING. Logged in as Admin even I cannot change the permissions.

The following users are all set to Deny:

- Creator Owner
- Domain Users
- Users
- System
- Administrators

How do I get around this and reset the permissions on the folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an administrator you will need to "take ownership" of the folder/files and then apply the permissions you require.

Look under **Advanced**

[image]

then **Owner**
[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you, this worked great with ONE hitch. Most/All of the subfolders in the main directory did the same D:

How do I take care of all of those in a fast manner?